# Leaking plastic on plastic water connector

Tags: water, leak, dishwasher, valve

[image][image][image]

I have a dishwasher with a small leak where the black plastic hose coming from the water inlet valve attaches to the dishwasher water inlet (on the left side of the dishwasher body).  The leak is at the location near the tip of the green pencil in the photo.

The hose is being held on by a spring clamp and it seems to be in good working order.

My question: is there a trick to stopping water leaks from this junction?  Is there an equivalent of a plastic-on-plastic pipe dope that I can put on the tubing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this might be crazy simple: petroleum jelly (Vaseline, etc). Make sure it's the plain stuff (i.e. not medicated), then take the hose off and smear some around the edges, then fit the hose back on. It's remarkable how well it stops minor leaks like this.

Comment: They also have silicone grease made for this, typically sold with the faucet repair items at the home store.  That _might_ be safer for more plastics and rubbers.

Comment: Actually I've used this for some amazing fixes (my wife always has a jar) and I've never had a problem with it damaging plastic or rubber. I would say it might be the safest stuff around. And it even fixed dried-out connections to boot

Comment: @JPhi1618 - thanks for your comment!  Have you seen, by chance, if the silicone grease used in these types of repairs are also food safe?  I imagine that a small amount will be washed onto the dishes as it enters with the rinse/washing water.

Comment: Cool, good to know that petroleum jelly works in practice.  The internet tells you it degrades some plastics, but probably a tiny consideration in the real world.

Comment: @Han, the grease is sold for lubricating faucet parts that directly touch the water coming out of the faucet so... I imagine it's safe?  Actually I found [this item](https://www.amazon.com/Waterproof-Silicone-Grease-1-Pack-88693/dp/B000DZFUPC) which is listed as food safe.  Petroleum Jelly is also safe and maybe easier to find.

Comment: @Han Silicone is probably safer overall (especially since it's made to do this), but the regular petroleum stuff is typically something you already have in your house and a LOT cheaper. If it is riskier, we're probably talking minimally. Anecdotally it's not failed me yet.

Comment: In addition to all the above good suggestions, when you remove the black hose to lube it up, examine the white piece going into hose to make sure there's not a pinhole or crack in it.